# Using Cumulative function for Rectangular Placement

Tags: constraint-programming, minizinc

I have a rectangular placement problem. What I want is to place rectangles of size x by y into another rectangle without overlapping. What I want in the end is the starting point of each rectange.

I made this part OF code for it, the logic was that it would cumulatively check for x and y axis along the height and width of the function. However, when I run this, it works for a few instances but not for others. So I posted one of the specific instances for which it gives repeat points here to ask what the issue is and what changes can be made.

Thank you

```
constraint cumulative(start, x, y, height);
constraint cumulative(starty, y, x, width);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should work if you add the `diffn` constraint which constraint the boxes to be non overlapping, i.e.

```
include(globals.mzn);
....
constraint diffn(start,starty,x,y);
...
```

See https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/lib-globals.html?highlight=diffn for more about `diffn`.

One of the 10752 solutions is:

```
15  15
10
1: 3 3  0 9
2: 3 4  12 0
3: 3 5  12 10
4: 3 6  12 4
5: 3 7  9 8
6: 3 8  9 0
7: 3 9  0 0
8: 3 12 3 0
9: 3 15 6 0
10: 6 3 0 12
```

I checked on paper that this is a proper solution, i.e. no overlapping and all cells in the 15x15 box are covered.

Comment: Thank you, this is working very well.

I have one question about how I can reduce processing time for larger arrays when I run this function. Thank you

Comment: In general you can try with different solvers (e.g. Chuffed and Gecode) and test different search heuristics, see https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/mzn_search.html for more about this.

Answer (score 4):

Cumulative will only check the resource usage  in it's single dimension (which is useful and can give good pruning sometimes), it does not ensure the no-overlaps property. The [`diffn` global constraint](https://www.minizinc.org/doc-2.4.3/en/lib-globals.html#packing-constraints) is the canonical one to use for ensuring no-overlap.